# Only one Azure subscription is showing in the IoT Workbench: Cloud Azure provision command

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, iot-workbench, mxchip

I have set up my MXChip(Azure IoT Dev Kit) with Azure Provision. But I moved all of my Azure resources to a different subscription now. And I need to do the Azure Device Provisioning again so that the MXChip device can be provisioned with a new connection string. But when I try to do the commands it shows only one subscription.

```
IoT Workbench: Cloud
Azure Provision
```

[image]

Any idea what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem here. If you look at the Extension Azure IoT Device Workbench, you can see that there are dependencies of Azure IoT Hub Toolkit and Azure Account.

[image]

Now, if you go to the Azure Account Extension commands, you can see that there is command Azure: Select Subscription.

[image]

You can use this command by pressing F1 in vscode.

```
Azure: Select Subscriptions
```

There you can select all the subscriptions that you need to work with and click OK.

[image]

Once you are done, you can try `Azure Provision` again, I am sure your subscription will show up there.